# Apache - Load only certain modules based on remote hsot

Tags: apache-2.2, .htaccess

We are trying to figure out how to "load"  in htaccess based on remote ip.

We want to use the limit-connection-per-ip(rate limit module) but only for certain ip's ?

Can this be done ?
Any other way to "Rate Limit Apache Connections" ?

Answer (score 1):

This may be better accomplished in your firewall.

[Here's an example](http://fernandoipar.com/2009/06/17/iptables-trick-to-limit-concurrent-tcp-connections/) in IPTables, though it's written with MySQL in mind.